# Does random forest (and, decision tree) require an independent observation assumption?

Tags: random-forest, cart, independence

I am wondering if random forest models require an independent observation assumption.

My date includes observations from the same participants, but I do not have a way to identify each participant. I would like to analyze this using random forests or decision tree, but I am not sure if I have to worry about the independent assumption like regression models or not.

I would appreciate your guidance and literature would be of great help.

Comment: I do not think that having independent observations is essential. The main theoretical results on random forests rely on the law of large numbers and that works for correlated data.

Comment: Thank very much for your comment, @stans-ReinstateMonica! I am happy to hear that it seems like I can use random forests with my data! Do you happen to know any articles that I can cite? I would like to back up my analysis choice for writing a journal article. :)

Comment: Sorry, do not know of articles. I suggest examining standard references and the articles mentioned therein.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Okay, I will further read into it. I hope you have a great day!

Comment: Thank you. You too.